# R control memory usage in doParallel

Tags: r, rjava, jri

I use doParallel for batches of tasks but it seems R is not freeing up memory even I call rm() and gc(). So my program always exit out of memory. It may be worth to mention that I am running R from Java by using JRI, but I think it is not Java issue but R. This is because (1) by monitoring JVM memory consumption, it was never beyond 3GB (allocated max=8G); (2) I am running a job on a company server, allocating total of 36G to the job (8G for JVM). The job always exits due to a system error (max memory 36G reached), NOT java's outofmemory exception. To me it suggests that the R engine that Java calls has gradually used up all memory available.

Below is the R code and some Java code. The java code is very complex so I tried to simplify it by just outlining the general structure.

```
REngine re = ....
eng.parseAndEval("registerDoParallel("+cpuCores+")")    

while(someCondition){
    String dataMatrixFile=functionToGetDataMatrixFile("..."); /the file path
    //is different in each iteration of the while loop
    re.parseAndEval("m <- read.table('"+dataMatrixFile+"', header=FALSE, sep=',', skip=0)"); //read data matrix saved on the disk
    re.parseAndEval("d <- dist(m, 'euclidean')"); //compute distance matrix
    re.parseAndEval("clustering <- hclust(d, 'average')"); //do hierarchical 
    //clustering on the distance matrix

    re.parseAndEval("b <- c(1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, ......)"); //a set of number
    //of clusters to cut the dendrogram. the exact size of b and values 
    //depend on a java function. but lets just assume here we get a vector
    //of integers, and there can be 20-100 elements.

    Object result = re.parseAndEval("foreach(i=b, .combine=c, .packages='fpc') %dopar% {\n
               subgraph <-cutree(clustering, k=i)
               calinhara(m, subgraph)
               }"); //line A. use doParallel to iterate through b, cut the
    //dendrogram, and compute the calinski & harabasz statistic. The object 
    //returned by the foreach block is a vector of double values

    re.parseAndEval("rm(list=ls())");
    re.parseAndEval("gc()"); //line B
    re.parseAndEval("gc()");                

    javaFunctionToProcess(result); 
}
```

By logging it seems to be the block of code indicated by "line A" that is causing memory leak, as each time the program breaks I can see in the log that it is executing that block. So my question is how to fix this, but it might be helpful if someone can explain some of the specific questions below

1) in the foreach block, does R create multiple copies of the object "clustering", one for each core to parallelize?

2) if yes to 1), are these duplicate objects garbage collected automatically? If not that could be the cause to memory leak

3) is it necessary and would it help to change line A to:

```
Object result = re.parseAndEval("foreach(i=b, .combine=c, .packages='fpc') %dopar% {\n
               subgraph <-cutree(clustering, k=i)
               calinhara(m, subgraph)
               gc()
               gc()
               }");
```

4) is it necessary and would it help to "force" R to release memory by exiting the R environment, and re-create an R instance periodically, e.g., like this:
    re.parseAndEval("q()");
    re = null;
    re = [code to create a new REngine];
    ...//continue processing

Any suggestions very much appreciated!

Comment: add 1) yes, `clustering` and `m` are exported automatically. add 3) this seems to be worth a try (although I do not understand why you use `gc()` twice). Also an additional `rm(list=ls())` may help. add 4) I would rather try to stop and create a new cluster object from time to time than creating new R instances.

Comment: thanks I will try 3). As for 4), I use "registerDoParallel" which automatically creates and manages a cluster. If I understand, the disposal of the cluster is automatically managed? If not, how do I "stop" it?

Comment: I always use something like `workers=makeCluster(cpuCores);registerDoParallel(workers);#dostuff;stopCluster(workers);`

Comment: Look at the help page of `stopCluster`. It says "It is good practice to shut down the workers by calling stopCluster: however the workers will terminate themselves once the socket on which they are listening for commands becomes unavailable, which it should if the master R session is completed (or its process dies)."

Comment: I have done some experiments so far. It seems that 3) breaks the procedure as no meaningful results can be computed after gc() is added. Only when gc() is removed, I get consistent, meaningful results. Although I do not understand why, it seems gc() is causing unexpected variable deletion. I am still testing other methods, my data is very large and it is taking long time... will update later

Comment: One important point that I have missed is that as soon as you add `gc()` as the last line of the body of your `foreach` function, the function will return what is returned by `gc()`. But you want `calinhara(m, subgraph)` to be returned. You can try to add `on.exit({rm(subgraph,envir=environment());gc();})` as the first line in the body. In that case, the foreach function body will return `calinhara(m, subgraph)`.

Comment: thanks, that's very useful